# Same Height Cards in Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm developing an application using Ionic and on the first page, I'm Trying to use Ionic Grid system to show some cards with an image background. 
The Problem is that When I visit the page in the size of my own laptop's display everything is fine and cards have same height!

[Size of the Display Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXPha.png)

But once I resize the browser window the second card height changes (or Using Chrome's Emulator)
I want these two to have the same height in any situation. I've tried to fix this but no success.

[Half size of the Display Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQg1l.png)

Here's the Snippet I've made. It's not my full code but it demonstrates the Issue I have.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ionicApp">
  <ion-content>
    <!-- Row -->
    <div class="row row-center">

      <div class="col col-75">
        <!-- Card -->
        <a href="{link to a part}">
          <div class="card">
            <!-- Image of the Card -->
            <div class="item item-image">

              <img class="card-bg" src="http://placehold.it/800x200"/>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-25">
        <!-- Card -->
        <a href="{link to a part}">
          <div class="card">
            <!-- Image of the Card -->
            <div class="item item-image">

              <img class="card-bg" src="http://placehold.it/500x400"/>

            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mamos98/cysjn14t/)

Comment: if you can, add a live `jsfiddle` with your `html` and `css` codes.

Comment: Dear @jiff I added both JSFiddle and Snippet above in the Question.

Comment: Have you tried to add `fixed height` for images?

Comment: @jiff How do you suggest to do it? 'cause I've tried different ways of fixing this issue. I'm looking for solutions actually

Comment: I mean this `img.card-bg {
    height: 100px;
}`

Comment: @jiff Yes, I've tried before. Does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you are using `item-image` class, Ionic sets images width to `100%` and when you test your app on laptop or desktop, the right image can be shown in `100%` of width and `100%` of height, but when you test your app on phone, when browser tries to set the image width to `100%`, the image height changes to less than `100%‍‍‍‍`, and as you've seen the height of images is different, you should change your strategy

Comment: Rasool Jan Thanks for your reply. I will consider it. But the problem is that the correct and sufficient way of adding a picture to a card in Ionic is to use a `<div>` with `item-image` tag. I'm looking for CSS solutions for this. Maybe it can be solved using FlexBox but I don't know how. I will wait for more answers and If didn't receive any, I'll try to make my own customized grid system ;)